# Write out multiple text files from a large list

Tags: r

I want to output tables from a list of 64 items, retaining the file names of the 64 items. My data takes the form:

```
ANNUAL.PRED    Large list (64 elements, 1.4 Mb)
file1 : num [1:251, 1:12] 35.23 74.09 ...
-------------------------------------------------
file64: num [1:96, 1:12] 102.4 107.6 ...
```

I have tried the following approach:

```
invisible(lapply(names(ANNUAL.PRED), function(x){
write.table(ANNUAL.PRED, file=paste(x, ".txt", sep="\t")
}))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(file1 = c(35.2264588125098, 74.0906522082933, 52.2975727774542,  :
>        arguments imply differing number of rows: 251, 145, 100, 96, 241, 240, 242, 243

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I have used a similar approach to output multiple plots in this manner and it has worked.

Comment: A few issues i can spot off hand : 1) You are passing the whole list to `write.table`, each time, rather than one list item per `write.table` call. 2) You probably mean to pass `sep="\t"` as an argument to `write.table` but above you have it as an argument to `paste`.

Comment: This is a good point @arvi1000, because when the output files are created in my directory, it prints FALSE when I pass the argument "header=FALSE." How can I make the sep and header parts arguments to write.table rather than paste?

Comment: Never mind, I got it by simply adding the write.table arguments after first closing the brackets for the paste arguments.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trial and error, I solved this with a slight modification on the above:

```
invisible(lapply(names(ANNUAL.PRED), function(x){
write.table(ANNUAL.PRED[x], file=paste(x, ".txt", sep="\t")
}))
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the answer and what you tried before hand.

Comment: Sorry @leroyJr - i left out the key change but have now amended it. The subset [x] after the ANNUAL.PRED made the difference.